# DiscordJS Roles Won't Add

Tags: discord

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const { Permissions } = require("discord.js");
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("mute")
        .setDescription("Mute a user on the server")
        .addUserOption((option) =>
            option
                .setName("user")
                .setDescription("The user you want to mute")
                .setRequired(true)
        ),
    execute: async (interaction) => {
        const user = interaction.options.getUser("user");
        if (!interaction.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_ROLES)) {
            return interaction.editReply({
                content: `:x: | Manage Roles Permission is required to perform that action!`,
                ephemeral: true,
            });
        }
    user.roles.add(member.guild.roles.cache.get("958443243836702859"));
        return interaction.editReply("Muted!")
    },
};
```

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
It won't let me add a roles to a user please help!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `user.roles.add()` in the middle of the hash definition of `module_exports`.

Read through your code again.  It's a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue stems from this, `roles` is an element of a `member` which is the parent of a `user`. `user` does not contain the element of `roles`. The code was trying to add roles to a `user` rather than a `member`.

This will help you out.

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const { Permissions } = require("discord.js");
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("mute")
        .setDescription("Mute a user on the server")
        .addUserOption((option) =>
            option
                .setName("user")
                .setDescription("The user you want to mute")
                .setRequired(true)
        ),
    execute: async (interaction) => {
        const user = interaction.options.getUser("user");
        if (!interaction.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_ROLES)) {
            return interaction.editReply({
                content: `:x: | Manage Roles Permission is required to perform that action!`,
                ephemeral: true,
            });
        }
//adding the below line
    const member2mute = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(user.id)
//changing the below line
    member2mute.roles.add("958443243836702859");
        return interaction.editReply("Muted!")
    },
};
```